# How to load tf.keras models with keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I've been using the keras module from tensorflow 1.12.0 for training and saving models.  I recently came across a seemingly useful library for visualization of the weights/outputs, but they require the models be loaded as a Keras model.  I'm running into an error trying to load my `tf.keras` models using keras, and was hoping someone could provide a solution.  Python version 3.5.2, Keras version 2.2.4.

I've defined the custom object for the `GlorotUniform` since keras doesn't recognize that initializer.  Afterwards, when I try to load the model, I get a `TypeError`.

```
# This works
model = tf.keras.models.load_model('./densenet_model.h5')

# This does not work
model = keras.models.load_model('./densenet_model.h5', custom_objects={"GlorotUniform": tf.keras.initializers.glorot_uniform})

# This is the error that happens
TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not list
```

In summary, I was wondering if there was a simple way to convert a model created with `tf.keras` to a keras model.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a workaround.  I just load the model with tf.keras.load_model, then save_weights.  Then I build the same model with Keras and just use load_weights.  I verified that the weights were loaded appropriately by checking the output with my validation dataset.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `from keras.models import load_model` I used `from tensorflow.python.keras.models import load_model`. The problem is solved.