# convert tensorflow.keras model to keras model

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

I have an EfficientNet model (tensorflow.keras==2.4) and would like to use [innvestigate](https://github.com/albermax/innvestigate) to inspect the results, but it requires keras==2.2.4

Training code:

```
tensorflow.keras.__version__ # 2.4

model = tf.keras.applications.EfficientNetB1(**params)

# do training

model.save('testModel')
```

I have the model saved as file but can not load it into Keras 2.2.4. This is the point where I'm stuck, I couldn't figure out what to do to convert the model.

Use Innvestigate:

```
keras.__version__ # 2.2.4

keras.model.load_model('testModel')  # Error

# some more stuff...
```

I also found this thread, might try it, but since efficient net has > 350 layers it is not really applicable
[How to load tf.keras models with keras](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55938313/how-to-load-tf-keras-models-with-keras)

I don't know if it's actually possible to convert models between tensorflow.keras and keras, I appreciate all help I can get.

Answer (score 0):

Due to version incompatibility between tensorflow as keras, you were not able to load model.

Your issue will be resolved, once you upgrade `keras` and `tensorflow` to `2.5`.